# No funciona ningún evento en React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy programando con React una lista con imagen con comentarios, pero no funciona ningún evento , `onClick`, `onChange`, etc, no sale ningún error, y el componente se renederiza correctamente, solo que no se puede hacer nada, veo en devtools, y tampoco ocurren cambios.

he intentado de muchas formas pero no funciona nada

```
onClick={this.remove.bind(this,i)}
onClick={()=>console.log(i)}
onClick={()=>{console.log(i)}}
```

incluyendo reiniciar navegador, cache, etc, no se puede capturar evento click

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
export default class Checks extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cmsg: "",
            obs: "",
        };
        this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
        this.Add = this.Add.bind(this);
        this.Sus = this.Sus.bind(this);
    }
    remove(i) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    Add(i) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    Sus(i) {
        console.log(i);
    }   
    TCu(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
    render() {      
        const dts = this.props.lista.map((item, i) =>
            <tr key={i} style={{ 'textAlign': 'center' }}>
                    <td>
                        <img src={uri + "/" + item.imagen} className="card-img" style={{ "maxWidth": "100px", "float": "left", 'height': '100px' }} alt={uri + "/" + item.imagen} />
                    </td>
                <td className="centro">
                    <div className="quantity">
                        <input name="quantity-number" className="quantity-number" id="" className="quantity" type="text" defaultValue={item.cantidad} required />
                        <span onClick={() => this.Add(i)} className="inc quantity-button">+</span>
                        <span onClick={() => this.Sus(i)} className="dec quantity-button">-</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td className="centro">
                    <a href="#!" onClick={() => this.remove(i)} className="btn" style={{ 'backgroundColor': 'white', 'color': 'grey', 'fontSize': '40px' }}> <i className="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
        return (
            <div className="" style={{ "padding": "20px" }}>
                <table className="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style={{ 'textAlign': 'center', 'textTransform': 'uppercase' }}>Imagen</th>
                            <th style={{ 'textAlign': 'center', 'textTransform': 'uppercase' }}>Cantidad</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {dts}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <textarea className="form-control" rows="13" name="obs" value={this.state.obs} onChange={this.TCu.bind(this)}></textarea>
                <input value={this.state.cmsg} onChange={this.TCu.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas agregando un onclick a una etiqueta `span` eso no se puede hacer, ni siquiera en javascript puro. debes de cambiar de etiqueta (a un `div`) y te funcionara.

Comment: ok, pero tampoco funciona onchange, la cual si va en un input, podria deverse sólo a eso?

Comment: @Shassain en que te basas para decir eso? `span` es un elemento como `div`. No se porque dices que no se puede.

Comment: puedes probar lo siguiente `onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}` para ver si el click funciona. Y el problema esta en los metodos que  llamas

Comment: @hawks tampoco muestra nada

Comment: es muy raro. Quizá el `span` no tiene `width` o `height` y por eso no detecta el click ya que el elemento no tiene tamaño. Puedes inspeccionar el elemento y ver si es eso?O mirar de poner `display: block` al `span`? Prueba a ver

Comment: sí tienes razón semanticamente tendran significados diferentes per cuando digo "`span` es un elemento como un `div`" me refiero que todos los elementos `html` heredan de la interfaz base `HTMLElement` y por lo tanto se puede manipular como cualquier otro elemento.  Aquí la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). Esto es falso "Estas agregando un onclick a una etiqueta span eso no se puede hacer, ni siquiera en javascript puro. debes de cambiar de etiqueta (a un div) y te funcionara"

Comment: por mi vale abre un chat pero otra vez te equivocas si yo defino el `onclick` directamente en el `span` como va escucharlo el padre si no tiene un listener definido para el `click`?

Comment: Acabo de 'run' tu componente y funciona, el onChange y el onClick! no suman nada ni restan pero pasan por la console del navegador los eventos de texto añadido y contador de eventos click.(he añadido una lista [let lista = ['abc','def'])y he map()

Comment: Te está devolviendo algún error o advertencia en la consola?

Comment: no devuelve nada, pero tampoco hace algo